# Need specific sturucture for area calc using regex

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I am creating area calculator for that i need specific format 
i want regex format for my specific format 
format is like**

**123'12"1/2**

user can add first 3 digit for feet then 2 digit for inch and one - one value for fraction i need all sign that i specify in format.

Comment: And... what have you tried so far?

Comment: It's not very clear what you need the regex to do.. Do you want to pull out the different numeric values? If so, something like `/(\d+)'(\d+)"(\d+\/\d+)` might work. Could do with some more clarity on your requirements though.

Comment: i don't know regex @ reedomn-m

Comment: i need first 3 digit for feet , next 2 for inch and last fraction value

Comment: This is a great resource for learning and testing regex expressions. http://regexr.com/

Comment: I reformatted the question to fix grammatical issues and make it easier to read. Please check my other comment for a resource in learning regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should work:

```
var area = '123\'12"1/2'; // note you'll need to escape any single quotes
var regex = /(\d+)'(\d+)"(\d+\/\d+)/;
var matches = area.match(regex);

console.log(matches[1]); // feet
console.log(matches[2]); // inches
console.log(matches[3]); // fraction
```

This will work even if you feet number isn't 3 digits, and your inches aren't 2 digits, e.g. `99'1"1/12`

Comment: i think in feet if i use 4 digit i'll work same in inch and fraction